# Order that apache process rules in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a very complex directory structure in this server I am working and lots of htaccess on multilevel. I know apache merges the configurations from all htaccess but it's not that easy as it sounds...

For example, if an htaccess file close to the root makes use of "Filesmatch" to set configurations, then if I try to change those same configurations in another htaccess file on a deeper directory without using "Filesmatch" the configurations are not changed. I realized I can only change them if I use Filesmatch ".*".

I think I know why: apache processes some things first and others later despite the order they are placed inside an htaccess file.

So I would like to know this: is there a solid documentation where I can see clearly what apache processes first and what later? I mean, even in the same htaccess files some rules "dont look" to work in the exact order they appear inside the file cause somethings are probably executed in a different order.

Comment: Apache checks rewrite rules from top to bottom.

Comment: Yes, but if you mix rewrite rule with filesmatch you will see you will have problems in some case cause even if you place your rewriterules on top of the file and filesmatch rules at the bottom, the filesmatch will match FIRST!

Comment: I'm not sure why you would mix filesmatch and rewriterule.

Comment: ... everything has a case usage, if not Apache could drop permanently files filesmatch ... and rely only on mod_rewirte.

Comment: `FilesMatch` is not intended to be used with `mod_rewrite` at all. It is intended for use with other directives such as `AddDefaultCharset`, `Require valid-user`, and `DefaultLanguage`, amoung others. If you find you're using `FilesMatch` for in your rewriting rules, then you're probably not rewriting correctly. If you're having trouble, post the content of your rules in a new question, explaining exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Asking this question to Apache community they provided me the answer very easily! It's here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging

> The configuration sections are applied in a very particular order. Since this can have important effects on how configuration directives are interpreted, it is important to understand how this works. The configuration sections are applied in a very particular order. Since this can have important effects on how configuration directives are interpreted, it is important to understand how this works.
>
> The order of merging is:
>
> - `<Directory>` (except regular expressions) and `.htaccess` done simultaneously (with .htaccess, if allowed, overriding `<Directory>`)
> - `<DirectoryMatch>` (and `<Directory "~">`)
> - `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>` done simultaneously
> - `<Location>` and `<LocationMatch>` done simultaneously
> - `<If>`

Comment: Also note, that `Directory`, `DirectoryMatch`, `Location`, and `LocationMatch` can ony be used in the config files.  Only `Files` and `FilesMatch` can *also* be used in `.htaccess` files.  It will combine everything from withing the config file and the htaccess files, in the order indicated.